# How can I create a multi-color banner with text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have right now:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<p>Text here</p>
<div id="right"><p>Text here</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
font-size:25px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:red;
}

#right{
background-color:#53EDF0;
margin-left:50%;
}
```

The two sides are split correctly but the left background only covers half of the banner vertically.

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
div 
{ 
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.red 
{
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
}

.blue
{
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="red">Text</div><div class="blue">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just had to add a float:left to the div block.

Comment: @Henry well, I would suggest against floating too often.  It has it's advantages in certain situations but don't rely on it by any means it can get messy!

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without the float? When I used your code exactly there was a line break between the two. Also, would you mind explaining why floating is bad? I know it has something to do with messing up the element flow, but I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content, #right {
    font-size:25px;
    color: #53EDF0;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

#right{
    color: red;
    background-color:#53EDF0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't accomplish a second background color.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest the following http://jsfiddle.net/BTmtY/

HTML (use classes instead of ids)

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="left"><p>Text here</p></div>
    <div class="right"><p>Text here</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS (create two blocks and float them)

```
#content{
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:red;
}
#content:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
.right, .left {
    width: 50%;
}
.right p, .left p {
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
}
.right{
    background-color:#53EDF0;
    float: right;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
```

If you need more styling, like font color change just add something to *.left* and *.right* classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit modified sample:

```
<div class="content">
    <span>Text here</span>
    <span class="right">Text here</span>
</div>

.content{
    float: left;
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:red;
    width: 100%;
}
.content span { float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center; }

.right{
    background-color:#53EDF0;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkocjancic/Asdp6/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="content"><p>TEXT 1</p></div>
<div id="right"><p>TEXT 2</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
color:#53EDF0;
background-color:red;
width:50%;

}

#right{
background-color:#53EDF0;
margin-left:50%;
color:red;
width:50%;
margin-top:-109px;
} 

p {
    margin-left:20px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetiva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px;
    font-style:italic;
}
```